# Is there a way of editing gridview records without using a detailsview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a very wide gridview and I need to be able to update the records, however, I update the records inside the gridview, the gridview in edit mode goes out of the page. I tried a detailsview, but for some reason I wasn't able to update it.

I am trying to use a panel with textboxes, and I want to be able to select the gridview row and make the panel display in a modalpopup displaying the row information for me to update.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Asp.net in C#.

Are there any example codes that you guys might now of?

What do you recommend me doing in this situation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: go for `modalpopup` on `edit` button.

Comment: u can redirect the values in the panel on edit........

Answer (score 0):

I think you should for a `ModalPopupExtender` for the ease with which you can achieve what you want here.

Here is a very good [EXAMPLE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/edit-gridview-row-with-model-popup-extender-in-Asp-Net-ajax/)

Its a step-by-step guide on exactly what you want to do.